# Update all table rows but top N in Mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I was trying to run the following query

```
UPDATE blog_post SET `thumbnail_present`=0, `thumbnail_size`=0, `thumbnail_data`=''
WHERE `blog_post` NOT IN (
 SELECT `blog_post`
 FROM blog_post
 ORDER BY `blog_post` DESC
 LIMIT 10)
```

But Mysql doesn't allow 'LIMIT' in an 'IN' subquery.

I think I can make a select to count the table rows and then make an ordered update limited by 'COUNT - 10', but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think i understood you right:

```
update blog_post bp
left outer join
(
select 
 post_id -- what's your PK again ??
from 
 blog_post
order by
 post_id desc limit 10
) latest on latest.post_id = bp.post_id
set 
  bp.thumbnail_present = 0 -- add more fields
where
 latest.post_id is null;
```

**EDIT**

I've renamed the fields as you can't seem to take a hint !

```
update blog_post bp
left outer join
(
select 
 blog_post 
from 
 blog_post
order by
 blog_post desc limit 10
) latest on latest.blog_post = bp.blog_post
set 
  bp.thumbnail_present = 0
where
 latest.blog_post is null;
```

Comment: Couldn't get it to work, http://paste2.org/p/1184501 /* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'latest.post_id' in 'where clause' */ Any ideas?

Comment: that's right - what's your primary key field for blog_posts called ?? replace post_id with it !! oh i think your primary key has the same name as your table

Comment: no probs - btw, your primary key naming convention i.e using the same name as your table gives me the ebe jeebies

Comment: Actually I didn't designed the db, I'm just adding some functionality to someone else code.

Comment: no worries - i was just pointing out how confusing it was that's all :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE blog_post SET `thumbnail_present`=0, `thumbnail_size`=0, `thumbnail_data`=''
WHERE `blog_post` NOT IN (
    SELECT `blog_post` FROM
    (
     SELECT `blog_post`, (@rowNum := @rowNum + 1) rn
     FROM blog_post, (SELECT @rowNum :=0) b
     ORDER BY `blog_post` DESC
     ) a
 WHERE rn <= 10)
```

Comment: I couldn't understand the query at all :P But when I run it gives /* SQL Error (1248): Every derived table must have its own alias */

Answer (score 0):

limit is not supported in subquery, what you will have to do is put the limit on the outer query with update query. this way it will update only 10 rows

Comment: I don't know how to move the LIMIT to the outher query and get the desired results, can you detail?